# How to check if a b2Body exists in a Mutable Array?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have an array of b2Bodies to be removed at a safe point by my update loop, but occasionally I need to remove objects without adding them to this array. Before I do this I want to check to see if the body is already in the array, and if it is remove it so the object isn't deleted twice (causing an exception). I understand this would be simple if the body was an objective c object.

Objects are added to the array like this:

```
[bodiesToBeDestroyedMutableArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:body]];
```

Can I compare the objects in `bodiesToBeDestroyedMutableArray` to a given b2Body pointer to see if they are (pointing to) the same body? I've tried:

```
if ([bodiesToBeDestroyedMutableArray containsObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:body]])
```

and

```
for(NSValue *bodyValue in bodiesToBeDestroyedMutableArray) {
    b2Body *bodyToTest = (b2Body*)[bodyValue pointerValue];

    if(bodyToTest == body){
        NSLog(@"body found in bodies to be destroyed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmmm, looks fine to me. So the loop wasn't finding any b2Body? Could it really be that it was never in the array somehow?

Comment: Definitely could be the case. So testing equality the way I have in the for loop is acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't checked if the equality test you mentioned works correctly...

You could use body->SetUserData to set some kind of identifier (a tag) so that you can later check for equity between tags.

Just in case you have already set something else to the body as userdata (like in mi case) the same approach is valid by setting this "tag" to whatever you have as userdata.

For example:

```
// Get the user data
XXSomeClass *block = (__bridge XXSomeclass*)b->GetUserData();

// Retrieve body from array
// Might need to cast the returning item from the array with (XXTypeAtArray *)
XXTypeAtArray *item = [arrayOfBlocks objectAtIndex:block.tag];
```